# Ruby. Mocking in RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec, initializer, ruby-mocha

I have a problem with mocking. I have class DistanceMatrix and I would
like to indicate which method form_matrix was called in if/else
statement. I need to use mocha and RSpec. Any ideas?

```
class DistanceMatrix

 def initialize(*args)
    if args[0].class == String
      form_matrix(get_data_from_yaml(args[0], args[1]))
    elsif args[0].class == Array || args[0] == nil
      form_matrix(get_data_from_db(args[0]))
    end
 end

 def form_matrix(...)
  ...
 end

end
```

it tried:

```
describe DistanceMatrix, "when mocking ..." do
  it "should do call form_matrix" do
    DistanceMatrix.any_instance.expects(:form_matrix).with([1]).once
    DistanceMatrix.any_instance.expects(:get_data_from_yaml).with("file_name.yml").once.returns([1])
    DistanceMatrix.new("file_name.yml")
  end
end
```

but got error:

```
Failures:
  1) DistanceMatrix when mocking ... should do call form_matrix
     Failure/Error: DistanceMatrix.new("file_name.yml")
     unexpected invocation: #<AnyInstance:DistanceMatrix>.get_data_from_yaml('file_name.yml', nil)
     unsatisfied expectations:
     - expected exactly once, not yet invoked: #<AnyInstance:DistanceMatrix>.get_data_from_yaml('file_name.yml')
     - expected exactly once, not yet invoked: #<AnyInstance:DistanceMatrix>.form_matrix([1])
     satisfied expectations:
     - allowed any number of times, already invoked once: #<DistanceMatrix:0x9e48b40>.get_optimal_route(any_parameters)
     - allowed any number of times, already invoked once: #<Database::Distances:0x9d59798>.load_distances(any_parameters)
     # ./distance_matrix.rb:18:in `initialize'
     # ./tsp_algorithm_spec.rb:253:in `new'
     # ./tsp_algorithm_spec.rb:253:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Finished in 0.25979 seconds
```

I found that in RSpec we should use not .expects() but .should_receive(), so I tried:

```
describe DistanceMatrix, "when mocking ..." do
  it "should do call form_matrix" do
    DistanceMatrix.any_instance.should_receive(:form_matrix).with([1])
    DistanceMatrix.any_instance.should_receive(:get_data_from_yaml).with("file_name.yml").and_return([1])
    DistanceMatrix.new("file_name.yml")
  end
end
```

but got new failure:

```
Failures:
  1) DistanceMatrix when mocking ... should do call form_matrix
     Failure/Error: DistanceMatrix.any_instance.should_receive(:form_matrix).with([1])
     (#<Mocha::ClassMethods::AnyInstance:0x96356b0>).form_matrix([1])
         expected: 1 time
         received: 0 times
     # ./tsp_algorithm_spec.rb:251:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.26741 seconds
```

Comment: #should_receive is using rspec's mocking – you originally said you were using mocha.  If you want to use mocha you should configure that in the spec_helper.rb for your project.

Comment: What both of those errors are telling you is that form_matrix wasn't called as you expected.  I don't think the problem is with your test.  My guess is that what you're passing into the initializer is a wrapped string or something, so args[0].class != String.  have you stepped through it in a debugger to figure out what's going on?

Comment: No. How could I debug on linux terminal?

Answer (score 4):

I only have experience with using Mocha and not RSpec, but looking at the Mocha failure message, the key parts are these :-

```
unexpected invocation: #<AnyInstance:DistanceMatrix>.get_data_from_yaml('file_name.yml', nil)
unsatisfied expectations:
- expected exactly once, not yet invoked: #<AnyInstance:DistanceMatrix>.get_data_from_yaml('file_name.yml')
```

If you look at the ends of these lines, you will notice that `get_data_from_yaml` is not being called with the expected parameters. It is being called with `('filename.yml', nil)` and not `('filename.yml')` as expected.

This is happening because when you call `DistanceMatrix.new("file_name.yml")` in your test with only *one* argument and then inside `DistanceMatrix#initialize` `DistanceMatrix#get_data_from_yaml` is being called with `(args[0], args[1])` and since `args` is a single element array, `args[1]` will be `nil`.

Maybe this isn't how you expected Ruby to work, but the following demonstrates this behaviour :-

```
def foo(*args)
  puts "args[0]=#{args[0].inspect}; args[1]=#{args[1].inspect}"
end

foo("string") # => args[0]="string"; args[1]=nil
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DistanceMatrix.any_instance.expects(:form_matrix).with("String") # => supply the correct string param
```

or

```
DistanceMatrix.any_instance.expects(:form_matrix).with([]) # => supply the correct array param
```

I'm not sure what your get_data_from_db and get_data_from_yaml methods are doing, but you should be able to control those inputs as well to verify the correct arguments are being supplied to form_matrix.

**EDITED**
You'll have to use DistanceMatrix.any_instance instead of mocking on an instance variable because you're trying to mock something in the initializer.  Also, in case its unclear, you'll need to actually make the appropriate method call after you set up the mock in the lines above, e.g.

```
DistanceMatrix.new("SomeString")
```

**EDITED**

```
it "should do call #form_matrix with proper arguments" do
  DistanceMatrix.any_instance.expects(:form_matrix).with([1])
  DistanceMatrix.any_instance.expects(:get_data_from_yaml).with("foo").returns([1])
  DistanceMatrix.new("foo")
end
```

Comment: my both methods get_data_from_yaml and get_data_from_db return Array. I tried this:

describe DistanceMatrix, "when mocking ..." do
  it "should ..." do
    distance_matrix = DistanceMatrix.any_instance
    distance_matrix = mock
    distance_matrix.expects(:form_matrix).with(an_instance_of(Array))
    DistanceMatrix.new("file_name.yml", [1, 2, 3])
  end
end

but it doesnt work.

Comment: Ok, in that case, what I'd do is mock out the get_data_from_yaml and get_data_from_db methods to return two known values and set your expectations on those known values.  see edit above

Comment: I changed "expects" to "should_receive" and got new failure. see edit above.